# MySQL Profiling

Tags: mysql, profiling

in MySQL profiling can be set using `SET profiling = 1;`

The query `SHOW PROFILES;` displays the time taken by each query. I would like to know if this time includes just the execution time at server or does it also include the time taken to send the result to frontend.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/general-thread-states.html) the state `Sending data` is the time it takes to send the result to the client. Example:

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000024 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000005 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000051 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000010 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000022 |
| System lock                    | 0.000012 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000024 |
| init                           | 0.000043 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000008 |
| statistics                     | 0.000012 |
| preparing                      | 0.000011 |
| executing                      | 0.000004 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.125893 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000076 | -- here
| end                            | 0.000005 |
| query end                      | 0.000002 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000005 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000005 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000001 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000012 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000001 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000001 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000013 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000001 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000002 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

Update: On using the query cache, the status might be `sending cached result to clien`.